# Is second marriage forgiven

Tags: marriage

If you were in the world and got married before you were saved, but you divorced because it just wasn’t a healthy relationship, and you divorced your partner without him knowing until later when you told him, and you marry again, will you be commenting adultery? Will your second marriage be forgiven? Both marriages were civil; neither took place in a church.

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think that the main problem is that you're not specifying a particular branch of Christianity. Do you want an opinion based on Catholoc doctrine, the writings of the Church fathers, mainstream Protestant theology, or some other branches of Christianity's very large tree?

Comment: I was going to edit this question a bit, but I didn't understand how someone goes for a divorce and remarries without notifying their spouse.   Civilly, that's not just adultery, that's bigamy.   But yeah, what nick said, if you don't specify the branch of Christianity (and clarify how the remarriage happened), this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some verses from the Bible on the Christian view of marriage, divorce and remarriage:

> Luke 16:18: Everyone who divorces his wife and marries another commits adultery, and he who marries a woman divorced from her husband commits adultery.

> Matthew 5:32: But I say to you that everyone who divorces his wife, except on the ground of sexual immorality, makes her commit adultery, and whoever marries a divorced woman commits adultery.

> 1 Corinthians 7:10-11: To the married I give this charge (not I, but the Lord): the wife should not separate from her husband (but if she does, she should remain unmarried or else be reconciled to her husband), and the husband should not divorce his wife.

> Matthew 19:6-9: "So they are no longer two but one flesh. What therefore God has joined together, let not man separate." "Why then," they asked, did Moses command that a man give his wife a certificate of divorce and send her away?" He said to them, “Because of your hardness of heart Moses allowed you to divorce your wives, but from the beginning it was not so. And I say to you: whoever divorces his wife, except for sexual immorality, and marries another, commits adultery."

> Romans 7:2: For a married woman is bound by law to her husband while he lives, but if her husband dies she is released from the law of marriage.

> Mark 10:11-12: "And if she divorces her husband and marries another, she commits adultery." And he said to them, “Whoever divorces his wife and marries another commits adultery against her."

> Hebrews 13:4: Let marriage be held in honor among all, and let the marriage bed be undefiled, for God will judge the sexually immoral and adulterous.

> 1 Corinthians 7:10: To the married I give this charge (not I, but the Lord): the wife should not separate from her husband.

> 1 Corinthians 7:39: A wife is bound to her husband as long as he lives. But if her husband dies, she is free to be married to whom she wishes, only in the Lord.

> Romans 7:2-3: For a married woman is bound by law to her husband while he lives, but if her husband dies she is released from the law of marriage. Accordingly, she will be called an adulteress if she lives with another man while her husband is alive. But if her husband dies, she is free from that law, and if she marries another man she is not an adulteress.

There are more, but I think this is sufficient to show that Christians take their marriage vows seriously, regardless of whethere they were married in a church or not.